# How is the `mask` of `LV_ITEM` set in virtual list control?

Tags: c++, winapi

Mentioned in the documentations [Virtual List Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/virtual-list-controls?view=msvc-170#:%7E:text=LVIF_TEXT%20The%20pszText%20member%20must%20be,state%20member%20must%20be%20filled%20in.) or [LVITEMA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvitema#:%7E:text=LVIF_COLFMT,pszText%20member%20is%20valid%20or%20must%20be%20set.), a function like `OnGetdispinfoList()` handles the notification `LVN_GETDISPINFO` for the corresponding content, if it matches a flags like `LVIF_TEXT` (or sometimes others). However, we don't directly touch the items in a virtual list control like setting `newItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;` and then manually `SetItem(&newItem);`. So, when and where did the items get their `mask` status?

Comment: The WinAPI documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#virtual-list-view-style   MFC is not part of the WinAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mask` does not belong to the item, but to the request.  Some data is only needed in report (aka "detail") view.  It might also be affected by the update region -- a repaint doesn't need to paint columns that don't intersect the update region.

Comment: Nice perspective. But how can I understand adding more mask while handling `LVN_GETDISPINFO`, like `pItem->mask |= LVIF_STATE;` from the [sample project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists)?

Comment: @ripfreeworld `LVN_GETDISPINFO` tells you what information it wants, you don't tell it.

Comment: @ripfreeworld When processing `LVN_GETDISPINFO`, you are supposed to look at the `mask` that is provided, and then fill in only the `LVITEM` fields that are being requested. You don't modify the `mask` at all. So, for instance, when the ListView wants an item's text, it will send `LVN_GETDISPINFO` with `LVIF_TEXT` set, then you fill in `item.pszText`.